# How do you find the centre of gravity using moments?

Tags: classical-mechanics, average

I'm just working through this example (Example 2), using moments and resolving forces to find the centre of gravity of three particles.  I understand resolving the forces and finding $\bar{x}$, but I don't understand what's going on with finding $\bar{y}$ - since $\bar{y}$ is never perpendicular to the force (the weight), I don't see how it can be used for finding moments?

Unless is down (the direction weight goes) actually into the page and not in the negative $y$ direction?  I suppose it shouldn't matter...  This is very confusing!

Any help gratefully received, thank you!

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1):

Given a mass system $m_k,\ k= 1,\cdots, n$ and an axis $\eta$, the mass system first moment regarding $\eta$ is equal to the resulting mass at the so called center of mass, times the distance regarding $\eta$. Choosing the $y$ axis we have

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n m_k y_k = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n m_k\right)y_g
$$

then

$$
y_g = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n m_k y_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n m_k}
$$